# Blazor Custom Authentication Message Handler

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

this is config of my blazor wasm project

```
    builder.Services.AddOptions();
    builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();

    builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthStateProvider>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(s => s.GetRequiredService<AuthStateProvider>());
    builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationService>(s => webcontext.Authentication);

    builder.Services.AddTransient<AuthMessageHandler>();
    builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = AppModelContext.BaseUri).AddHttpMessageHandler<AuthMessageHandler>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("ServerAPI"));
```

and in login page

```
[Inject]
public IHttpClientFactory ClientFactory { get; set; }


  private async void Login()
        {
           try
            {
                var Client = ClientFactory.CreateClient("ServerAPI");
                var LoginResult = await Client.GetAsync("WebApis/Login/UserName=e.vali&Password=111");

            }
            catch (AccessTokenNotAvailableException exception)
            {
                exception.Redirect();
            }
        }
```

when I run project, in

```
var Client = ClientFactory.CreateClient("ServerAPI");
```

line
this exception was thrown

```
Unhandled Exception:System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider' while attempting to activate 'AppModel.Services.Authentication.AuthMessageHandler'.
```

how can I register IAccesstokenProvider service?

Comment: Firstly its not a good idea to send the login email and password in a query string, because query string is not SSL encrypted. Always send as a body of the request and use POST instead of GET.

Comment: Yes. thx. this is sample for better understanding